# Executing sqlite statement.executeBatch(), giving fatal error "EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION"

Tags: sqlite

I am using sqlite, while using Statement.executeBatch(), the jvm is crashing and giving following fatal error, There is no problem while using PreparedStatement.executeBatch().
I have created separate connection and Statement object from each update in database. The error is...

#

## A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

#

## EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d8fde5c, pid=1980, tid=3416

#

## JRE version: 6.0_16-b01

## Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )

## Problematic frame:

## V  [jvm.dll+0xfde5c]

#

## If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:

## http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp

#

THE INSERT METHOD IS....

private void runInsert(int records) {
  Statement stmt = null;
  try {
   connection = DriverManager
     .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:jdbcbatch.db");
   connection.setAutoCommit(false);
   stmt = connection.createStatement();
   for (int i = 0; i < records; i++) {
    stmt.addBatch("insert into customer values(" + i + ",\"vijith_"
      + i + "\",\"10th floor kaushik nagar serverspace_" + i
      + "\"," + i
      + ",\"11th floor kaushik nagar serverspace_" + i
      + "\")");

// Execute the batch for INSERT
   sDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
   eDate = 0L;
   System.out.println("INSERT started at " + sDate);
   int[] recordsInserted = stmt.executeBatch();
   eDate = System.currentTimeMillis();
   milli = (eDate - sDate);
   System.out.println("INSERT ended at " + eDate);
   System.out.println("INSERT Time Milliseconds= " + milli
     + "     in Seconds= " + milli / 1000);
   processTime.put("INSERT", milli);
   if (recordsInserted.length != records) {
    connection.rollback();
   }
   connection.commit();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  } finally {
   try {
    if (stmt != null) {
     stmt.close();
    }
    if (connection != null) {
     connection.close();
    }
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
   }
  }
 }

can somebody look into my problem, if you find anything helpful please do forward to me.
Thanks in advance.

B. Patel

Comment: Has the fatal error happened only a single time, or is it reproducible? That is, does it happen every time?

Comment: I am passing the number of records to be updated from command prompt till 5 it does not have any problem but when I give more than 5(10,15 or 20) it gives that fatal error, you can see the code I have pasted just below the error stack. I have checked the native method in .c file there is one prepare() method in this method getStringUTFChars() call is having problem, but still I can't say why it is failing because it it working for PreparedStatement and other statement type but not working for "Statement" type with executeBatch(), if I give records greater than 5 to update.

Comment: Here I am pasting the native method which gets called when we invoke executeBatch method.

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_com_guestlogix_posd_sqlite_NativeDB_prepare(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jstring sql)
{
    sqlite3* db = gethandle(env, this);
    sqlite3_stmt* stmt;

    const char *strsql = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, sql, 0);
    int status = sqlite3_prepare(db, strsql, -1, &stmt, 0);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, sql, strsql);

    if (status != SQLITE_OK) {
        throwex(env, this);
        return fromref(0);
    }
    return fromref(stmt);
}